# Need to run Excel macro with administrator mode in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

**I am writing this code in VB 6.0**

I have a excel file which has a macro in it. But macro will run if I open the excel as ADMINISTRATOR I got a following code that will open excel program as ADMINISTRATOR but I am unable to open the a particular excel macro file that is already saved in drive

*Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1*

‘this will open the excel with a new book

Sub Main()

ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe", Command, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL

End Sub

But I need to open the excel file saved in path **“C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Trading Robot\Automation_Ver3.0.xlsm”**, for ADMINISTRATOR I have not given any password and I have ADMINISTRATOR rights to my laptop
could someone please help me how this could be implemented using excel VB 6.0 in Windows 07 machine...?

Thanks in advance,
Arun C M

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you want to do, but this might help you out. It opens Excel via the `ShellExecute` command, opens a particular file, and then runs a macro:

```
Sub Main()

    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.exe", Command, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    With xl
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Trading Robot\Automation_Ver3.0.xlsm")
        .Run "YourMacroName"
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: The `GetObject` method will grab the first instance of Excel it finds, so make sure you don't already have Excel running before this executes.

Comment: Perfect code, I am looking exactly same, Thanks your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and assistance